# doing some action while comparing two arrays in Python

Tags: python

I want to know if there is a way to compare two arrays in a loop or without loop and do some actions relative to our comparison. 
for example: compare these two arrays element-wise and whichever has a larger number, gets 1 score and add the end add the total score.

A = [ 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ] 
B = [ 1 , 2 , 1 , 4 , 3 ]

A score :

B score :

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far? Please add this to your question using the [edit] function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) in combination with [`numpy.greater`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.greater.html).

With `numpy.where` you create a new array which gives a `1` score when `A > B` else `0`.

Then we use `A_score - 1` to reverse the array to get the score of B.

```
A_score = np.where(np.greater(A, B), 1, 0)
B_score = abs(A_score-1)

print(A_score)
print(B_score)
print(A_score.sum())
print(B_score.sum())
```

Output:

```
[0 0 1 0 1]
[1 1 0 1 0]
2
3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot erfan !!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept as answer if it helped you :) @FarjamHaghıghı